# Android Json - Array Adapter to list view - Multiple strings, multiple text fields

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

I think im going about this all wrong and just need a push in the right direction. I parsed my json information and set them to set fields, so each one can be called and displayed. Now this only works for 1 field at a time I can't load more than one using the adapter. Do I need to compile all of these arrays into one to be called via a custom adapter? Here is my code:

```
public class LocalJsonFileActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localjsonfile)));
        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = jsonReader.readLine()) != null;) {
            jsonBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonBuilder.toString());
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);


        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            name.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        }

        ArrayList<String> bloodtype = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            bloodtype.add(jsonObject.getString("bloodtype"));
        }

        ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            type.add(jsonObject.getString("type"));

        }

        ArrayList<String> dob = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

            String series = jsonObject.getString("dob");

            if (series.equals("December")) {
                dob.add(jsonObject.getString("dob"));
            }
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, R.layout.usercard, R.id.txttype, type));


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("jsonFile", "file not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("jsonFile", "ioerror");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("jsonFile", "error while parsing json");
    }
}
```

}

layout main is just a blank list view. My layout card has 4 fields 1 that is image view. But I can't seem to show more than 1 piece of information. Reading data in single fields and then outputting is great. I would just like to add the text to all fields.

Comment: Did you understand what I explained in my answer ?

Comment: Yes I did thank you for your advice. I am going to make a custom view adapter to pass the array to. Fingers crossed ill get it to work ;)  thanks.

Comment: Cool. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple fields like this, you need to create an ArrayList of object type. Now which object ? Make a class like this -

```
public class PersonData {

    private String name, bloodType, type, dob;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBloodType() {
        return bloodType;
    }

    public void setBloodType(String bloodType) {
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

In your LocalJsonFileActivity, parse and store the data like this -

```
ArrayList<PersonData> data = new ArrayList<PersonData>();

        for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
            PersonData mPersonData = new PersonData();
            mPersonData.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            mPersonData.setBloodType(jsonObject.getString("bloodtype"));
            mPersonData.setType(jsonObject.getString("type"));

            String series = jsonObject.getString("dob");

            if (series.equals("December")) {
                mPersonData.setDob(jsonObject.getString("dob"));
            }

            data.add(mPersonData);

        }
```

Use a custom adapter or modify the constructor of the adapter you are using to take data as type `ArrayList<PersonData>` as the parameter.

Then use these values in your adapter something like this -

```
holder.TextViewName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
holder.TextViewBloodType.setText(data.get(position).getBloodType());
holder.TextViewType.setText(data.get(position).getType());
holder.TextViewDOB.setText(data.get(position).getDob());
```

Don't copy the full code, try to understand how I did it and implement it in your project. Your implementation might be little different in the adapter, this is just a demo of how to do things like these.

Comment: Thanks that has helped. I will adapt my code and try to get it to work with this in mind.